# Convergence and vectors theories

Tags: isabelle

Is there a convergence theory in Isabelle/HOL? I need to define `∥x(t)∥ ⟶ 0 as t ⟶ ∞`.

Also, I'm looking for vectors theory, I found a matrix theory but I couldn't find the vectors one, Is there exist such theory in Isabelle/HOL?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence etc. are expressed with *filters* in Isabelle. (See the corresponding [documentation](http://home.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/~hoelzl/html-data/documents/hoelzl2013typeclasses.pdf))

In your case, that would be something like

```
filterlim (λt. norm (x t)) (nhds 0) at_top
```

or, using the `tendsto` abbreviation,

```
((λt. norm (x t)) ⤏ 0) at_top
```

where `⤏` is the Isabelle symbol `\<longlongrightarrow>`, which can be input using the abbreviation `--->`.

As a side note, I am wondering why you are writing it that way in the first place, seeing as it is equivalent to

```
filterlim x (nhds 0) at_top
```

or, with the `tendsto` syntax:

```
(x ⤏ 0) at_top
```

Reasoning with these filters can be tricky at first, but it has the advantage of providing a unified framework for limits and other topological concepts, and once you get the hang of it, it is very elegant.

As for vectors, just import `~~/src/HOL/Analysis/Analysis`. That should have everything you need. Ideally, build the `HOL-Analysis` session image by starting Isabelle/jEdit with `isabelle jedit -l HOL-Analysis`. Then you won't have to process all of Isabelle's analysis library every time you start the system.

I assume that by ‘vectors’ you mean concrete finite-dimensional real vector spaces like ℝ<sup>n</sup>. This is provided by `~~/src/HOL/Analysis/Finite_Cartesian_Product.thy`, which is part of HOL-Analysis. This provides the `vec` type, which takes two parameters: the component type (probably `real` in your case) and the index type, which specifies the dimension of the vector space.

There is also a pre-defined type `n` for every positive integer `n`, so that you can write e.g. `(real, 3) vec` for the vector space ℝ³. There is also type syntax so that you can write `'a ^ 'n` for `('a, 'n) vec`.

Comment: Thanks Manuel for your extensive explanation. For `∥x(t)∥ ⟶ 0 as t ⟶ ∞`, `x` is a real vector and each element in this vector should converge to zero as t (time) is converge to infinity. I still have difficulties with Isabelle, such as, does x$i is the same as ('a,'b) vec?. Can I do some relations (mult, add, etc.) between vectors and matrixes?

Comment: Yes, but `∥x(t)∥ ⟶ 0` and `x(t) ⟶ 0` are completely equivalent. And, no, `x $ i` is the $i$-th component of the vector `x`, whereas `('a, 'b) vec` is the *type* of vectors whose components have type `'a` and whose dimension is `'b`. I.e. `(real, 3) vec` corresponds to ℝ³. Addition of vectors/matrices is done with `+`, dot product of vectors is `∙` (\<bullet>), matrix multiplication is `**`, vector/matrix multiplication is `v*`, and matrix/vector multiplication is `*v`. See the `Cartesian_Euclidean_Space` theory.

Comment: Thanks again Manuel, it is really useful. Honestly, I'm working on engineering problem and I'm investigating which theorem prover is more convenient. Two in the mind, Isabelle/HOL and PVS. I want to have a try with Isabelle first as I think it has more extensive theories already proven and the community is better in terms of the number of users.  Theorems or lemmas needed is related to real field such as inequalities, universally quantified inequalities, high order functions, norms, convergence, differential equations, ODE, trigonometric functions,    etc. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know PVS at all, so I really cannot comment on what its capabilities are and what kinds of background material they have available. Isabelle does have substantial material on everything you mentioned, but I could not possibly say whether we have everything you need.

Comment: Hopefully that Isabelle is the right choice. Cheers Manuel

Comment: I tried to work with _tends to_  with vectors `(real,3) vec`. The problem that I face is that I need to prove `(x≠0) ⟹ (∥x∥ ⟶ 0)` where `x` is a vector as  `t ⟶  ∞`. The available definition for  _tends to_ is for a function for example `real => real`. I defined it like `x≠0 ⟹((λt. norm (x)) ⟶ 0) at_top` where `x = y -z` and `⋀i. y$i= f x` also `⋀i. z$i= g x`. Does this definition correct?